# Meteor refreshes after selecting file on android

Tags: meteor

Meteor refreshes itself after selecting file for upload on the Android browser. 
Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details? But I will take a guess in the dark...

I am assuming that you are selecting/uploading a file using a form. Try returning false at the end of the method to cancel the submit event and cancel the page refresh.